# Git remote shows both original and renamed file

Tags: git, github

Here are the steps I performed to reach the current state

1) Create a file abc.java and commit

2) Rename file abc.java to ABC.java and commit

3) Change local git config to ignorecase false for git to detect file case change

4) It worked on my local did a git commit and git push

But the issue is that my remote branch now has both the files abc.java and ABC.java but my local is fine. Dont know what to do to remove the old file from my remote branch and make it equivalent to my local.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `git pull` and `git rm abc.java`. And commit/push.

Comment: Nope it somehow then deletes both the file remotely

Comment: So now the original is gone from the repo, you can just add the renamed file now, right?